# Manual Unwrap Warping Seams

Tags: uv

I'm trying to unwrap this sign I am modeling but the unwrap is coming out distorted. I've tried converting to triangles as suggested [in this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19267/why-does-one-face-appears-so-warped-when-uv-unwraping) answer... but same result. I've tried making the hole using the Knife tool previously but it made the unwrap even more horrible.

http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33505

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Comment: Use cube projection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this block-shaped object just simply use **cube uv projection** and re-arange the pieces  like you want in uv editor.

For more complex shapes unwrap the planar part with **project from view** so they don't distort, **pin** them in uv editor with <kbd>P</kbd> and then unwrap the whole piece with just **Unwrap** (with setuped seams).

For multiple planar parts in your mesh do this multiple times to create uv islands each with undistorted pinned piece inside and then use welding (<kbd>W</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>) to join the islands. For best results smooth the welds with UV Sculpt's (<kbd>Q</kbd>) Relax brush.

Comment: In cube projection everything is stuck together and overlapping. http://i.imgur.com/8uFMpsW.jpg

When I go to do project from view it looks great. I press P to set it pinned. Then I flip to another side and Project from view and the pinned one disappears. Why does it disappear?

EDIT: It appears you must select only the faces you want pinned. Otherwise it thinks you want to re-project from view the ones you just did. So you must select only the visible faces... not select all

Comment: You need to move the islands not to overlap. Disable snapping and proportional editing, also turn off the "UV edit and selection in sync" button. Then select the selection type to islands and move them like you want. For the second method the pinning works only for Unwrap, it doesnt work for Project_From_View. You need to select only parts of your mesh and do it segment after segment if you have multiple planar segments.

Comment: Figured it out. Though I don't know how I would get a to-scale version of the inside of the circle.

http://i.imgur.com/47fhLRl.png?1

Comment: I dont know how you could do that precisely but you can apply some checker pattern test texture to it and then scale it so its ok - basically eyeball it.